# How to add Wagtail 'admin' menu to custom templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, wagtail

On templates that derive from the Wagtail Page model, there is a small Wagtail icon/menu in the lower right corner. This provides a quick way to edit the page and/or jump to the Wagtail Admin. However, this menu does not appear on custom view templates that are not derived from Wagtail Page model.

How can I tell Wagtail to display the small menu on my frontend templates, so the pages have consistent navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Wagtail user bar is rendered by placing in your template:

`{% load wagtailuserbar %}`

`{% wagtailuserbar 'top-left' %}`

I typically just put the above in `base.html`.  The `'top-left'` designation, of course, tells the template tag where to render the user bar.    [Reference](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/writing_templates.html?highlight=wagtailuserbar#wagtail-user-bar)

However, the wagtailuserbar is only rendered for Wagtail pages.  What you want to do is render the user bar with only the Go to Wagtail Admin option (because no other options would be relevant).  Therefore, you could create your own template tag and place it in `base.html` beside the `wagtailuserbar`.  You would set it up so that it renders if there IS NO `page` in the context (the `wagtailuserbar` template tag checks to make sure there IS a `page` in the context).  To create your tag, just start with the code from `wagtailuserbar.py` and modify it to create a template tag called `wagtailuserbar_admin_only` (untested):

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from wagtail.admin.templatetags.wagtailuserbar import get_page_instance
from wagtail.admin.userbar import (AdminItem)

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def wagtailuserbar_admin_only(context, position='bottom-right'):
    # Find request object
    try:
        request = context['request']
    except KeyError:
        return ''

    # Don't render without a user because we can't check their permissions
    try:
        user = request.user
    except AttributeError:
        return ''

    # Don't render if user doesn't have permission to access the admin area
    if not user.has_perm('wagtailadmin.access_admin'):
        return ''

    # Only render if the context does NOT contain a variable referencing a saved page
    page = get_page_instance(context)
    if page:
        return ''

    # Render the items
    rendered_items = [AdminItem()]

    # Render the userbar items
    return render_to_string('wagtailadmin/userbar/base.html', {
        'request': request,
        'items': rendered_items,
        'position': position,
    })
```

Then, to use in templates, place in `base.html`:

`{% load wagtailuserbar_admin_only %}`

`{% wagtailuserbar_admin_only 'top-left' %}`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @dan-swain. However, this doesn't seem to work for non-Wagtail templates. For some reason, the Wagtail menu still doesn't appear on Django templates rendered via a standard view.

Comment: I just realized that the `wagtailuserbar` tag was already in my base.html. The issue remains that the menu does not render on all views.

Comment: See revised answer

Comment: @Brylie-Christopher-Oxley Wondering if my answer solved your problem.